# Directional gravity for irregular shapes

Tags: python, game-engine, workflow, physics, logic-bricks

I saw the gravity demo video by @GoranMilovanovic and it was pretty cool. Unfortunately, it didn't help with my specific situation for two reasons.

- I'm mainly trying to do my game with just logic bricks
- my "planet" is a torus, not a sphere.

I need a workflow that will allow me to have an object always point toward the nearest portion of the torus (may need some code for that one), and then fall toward it. Unfortunately, linear velocity doesn't seem to be working, and neither does track to. is there a better way to do this?

[image]

Comment: A "Taurus" is a type of car . . . do you mean Torus?

Comment: Taurus, torus, nuance. I think it's actually zodiac bull and whatnot. and how do you know my planet isn't a car?